# No puedo recibir los datos via JSON en mi web

Tags: php, json, post

Necesito recibir datos de una aplicación que envía datos a través de un objeto JSON por POST en el cuerpo de la transmisión. El problema es que no obtengo ningún dato en el lado de la página web, o incluso no puedo estructurarlo para almacenar.
La aplicación que uso es "Beacon Scanner" disponible en Android y hace una lectura de beacons y envía los datos como vemos en la descripción de la propia aplicación, y en la dirección especificada (Logging endpoint) trato de insertar el código para recibir los datos y subirlos a la base de datos, pero no puedo ni verlo en la pagina y ni subirlo a la BD.
[image: print de la aplicación donde especifica la dirección final de envio de los datos y como se envian]

En la parte de la página web tengo el siguiente código:

```
include("uqroo/conecta.php");
$info = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($info, true);
var_dump($data);
$beacon_type = $_POST['beacon_type'];
$distance = $_POST['distance'];
$hashcode = $_POST['hashcode'];
$ibeacon_data = $_POST['ibeacon_data'];
$rssi = $_POST['rssi'];
$tx_power = $_POST['tx_power'];

$ordenAgregar = "INSERT INTO Beacon_cel (beacon_type,distance,hashcode,ibeacon_data,rssi,tx_power) VALUES ('$beacon_type','$distance','$hashcode','$ibeacon_data','$rssi','$tx_power')";
if (mysqli_query($con, $ordenAgregar)) {

}
else {
    echo ("Houve error   ".$tabla);
   
}
```

Lo que necesito es recibir los datos que envía la aplicación (son medidas de distancia) y almacenarlos en una base de datos. La aplicación me exporta los siguientes datos cuando toma la medida:

```
{
  "beacon_type": "ibeacon",
  "distance": 1.259794923522814,
  "hashcode": -275728978,
  "ibeacon_data": {
    "major": "3838",
    "minor": "4949",
    "uuid": "426c7565-4368-6172-6d42-6561636f6e73"
  },
  "isBlocked": false,
  "last_seen": 1646066247333,
  "manufacturer": 76,
  "rssi": -69,
  "tx_power": -64
}
```

He estado en este proyecto durante semanas y no he hecho ningún progreso. Gracias por alguien que me puede señalar en la dirección correcta. Desde ya, Gracias!!

Comment: Allí dice que te los manda por $_POST, por lo tanto yo miraria primero que estructura tiene el POST recibido con un `var_dump($_POST);` o bien un `print_r($_POST)` y sabiendo esa estructura recogeria los valores.  Agrega en la pregunta lo que saques de ese print_r para que podamos ayudarte mejor.  Lo que no estoy tan seguro es que pinta esto: `$info = file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: Gracias po su antención. mira hice lo que me comentastes y con un var_dump($_POST) me sale un array(0) { }, creo que la información no está llegando, es eso?

Comment: Exacto, no te esta llegando nada... hasta que no consigas ver algo alli no obtendras resultados... prueba tambien con `var_dump($_REQUEST)` por si acaso los envia de otra forma, pero lo dudo (ese REQUEST muestra tanto los POST como los GET)

Comment: Probe var_dump($_REQUEST) y realmente no obtengo ninguna información, el punto ahora es si estoy poniendo mal mi dirección web o si la aplicación no funciona bien.

Comment: Bueno, a ver, la página funciona, al menos desde el navegador, y puedo ver los var_dump que has hecho vacios, claro, no estoy mandando nada, solo abriéndola.  La cosa es saber si esa app funciona enviando los datos correctamente. Si tu puedes forzar el envio de los datos desde esa app pon lo siguiente al principio del script, sino no sabras que te manda:  `file_put_contents('log_app.log', print_r($_REQUEST, true));`.  De este modo te creará un archivo llamado `log_app.log` en la misma carpeta del script index.php que podrás revisar si se ha llenado y que valores ha mandado, y verificarlos bien

Comment: Y si despues de forzar eso varias veces ese archivo no está ni creado entonces es que no funciona el envio y no llegan las peticiones desde la app a tu web.  Piensa que ese archivo se sobreescribe en cada petición, tanto desde la app como desde la web, así que no te confundas realizando las pruebas desde ambos sitios a la vez.